# Stuck... need help.. Listview w/ Array Adapter

Tags: android, arrays, listview, onclick, adapter

Ok, so I have this application that takes a adress strings (from values/xml) and parses it  your current position) retuning a name, address and distance away.  This is then picked up by an arrayadapter and put up on a listview.  I cannot for the life of me get the list view to accept an onitemclick to start another activity, where I can launch a different view.  I did have it where I was getting the row, name and address to show through to an alert dialog, but in my efforts to get it to launch an activity, I lost that.

So does anyone have any thoughts?  I am using the following call to make my list and and arrays.  This is stripped down, so assume I have all the imports and proper formatting.  I know I am just missing something simple here...

```
public class Wf extends ListActivity {
private ArrayList<String> DistanceList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
   super.onCreate(icicle);

   // Bind the ListView to an ArrayList of strings.
   DistanceList = new ArrayList<String>();

ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
                                 R.layout.listbox_layout,
                                 DistanceList);
lv.setAdapter(aa);

//Call to get distance... here
}

 public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,int position, long id) {
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) docs:

> ListActivity has a default layout that
>   consists of a single, full-screen list
>   in the center of the screen. However,
>   if you desire, you can customize the
>   screen layout by setting your own view
>   layout with setContentView() in
>   onCreate(). To do this, your own view
>   MUST contain a ListView object with
>   the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

Your ListView does not have the correct ID.  Your code is incomplete but I suspect the listener is not being registered with the ListView.

Comment: I see.  Ok, I am actually attempting to use 4 listviews in a single scrollview.  I know, sounds crazy, but it being driven by a cosmetic requirement.  I wrote a custom listbox_layout for the font control and such.  I just wish I could find a good example of this somewhere.  Do you know anything?  I like to figure this stuff out on my own, but apparently I am getting dumber by the hour.

Thanks again,

Comment: Ok, got it.  Now, can I do this on more than one listview in a single parent view?  For example a scrollview that has 4 listviews?

Comment: @WJOH: If you want to use multiple ListViews I don't think you can use ListActivity.  You'd have to just use Activity and wire it up yourself.